# Python multiprocessing child process sys.exit vs raise Exception

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The main process hangs in the following code when child process invokes sys.exit(1). However it calls error_callback and exits gracefully when the child process instead raises an Exception. I am trying to

1. Understand what is the difference between the two?
2. How to handle sys.exit(1) effectively ?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import sys

def fn(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit(1)                         # code hangs up   
    # raise Exception('Test Exception')   # code exits gracefully 

def callback(result):
    print('Callback')

def run():

    errors = []
    def error_callback(e):
        errors.append(e)

    with mp.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        for i in range(3):
            pool.apply_async(fn, args=[i], callback=callback, error_callback=error_callback)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    for e in errors:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I am running this using python 3.7 on windows

Comment: AFAIK I read your code, the python starts a process in which it calls the method fn, but this call is wrapped in other code, e. g. catching all exceptions and calling the error_callback etc. So if you call sys.exit(1) in your fn I assume that the surrounding code of fn call cannot work properly. I assume that you can return a result from fn that is passed back through callback - buI we should check the documentation of  apply_async method.

Comment: yes: search for "apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback[, error_callback]]]])¶" in that [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). It tells you, that the system will call callback after exiting the method `fn` with e. g. `return 1` instead of your `sys.exit(1)` (and `print(f'Callback, result = {result}')` in your `def callback(result)`)- and as soon as the callback is finished, the process is stopped - so your `sys.exit(1)` finishes the process before it can call the callback - and apply_async waits until callback is called - in your case forever, therefore it hangs.

Comment: 1. the exception does not interfere inadequately with this multiprocessing library, sys.exit does
2. you should never use sys.exit(1)  - use the return value of the function - as far as I understand you want to be able to return a value etc.

Comment: I am using some other library function which calls sys.exit(1) rather than returning any error code. I Can't modify the library to return the value

Comment: ooh, damn, bad library design - then I would start a process in that function fn and check its exit code - then you will have the double amount of processes... and you have to transfer the arguments to that other process (calling a python script and inside it calling the library function, returning the result to the parent process and returing exit code 0 in success, ..., a lot of work. Or is there another way of running multiple processes without callbacks, just exit code and e. g. capturing stdout/stderr for result capturing in Python? Only programming own process pooling?